# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 | Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
class myFunc{
  def summatory(list: List[Int]): Int= list match{
    case Nil => 0
    case _ => list(1) + summatory(list.tail)
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:
"scalac -classpath . -d . main.scala
scala -classpath . Main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

How can I solve it?

Comment: You don't know if the list will have two elements, you want to use `0` rather than `1` to access the first element. Although, you may rather call `head` and avoid that accident again, or even better you use proper pattern matching: `case head :: tail => head + summatory(tail)`

Answer (score 3):

Collection indexes in Scala a zero-based, so quick fix would be to just use element at `0` index (otherwise your code will fail on the recursive call processing the last element):

```scala
case _ => list(0) + summatory(list.tail)
```

But better just use [pattern matching](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-lists-nil-cons-scala-match-case-expressions/):

```scala
def summatory(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
  case x :: xs => x + summatory(xs)
  case Nil     => 0
}
```

Or in particular case of sum - just use `sum`:

```scala
def summatory(list: List[Int]): Int = list.sum
```